# notification is android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have a notification that started in a service.
When user click on this notification, an activity starts.

My problem is: if user press back button in this activity, navigates to home screen instead of previous activity.

I want push new activity to existing task.

```
    Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
    openIntent.setAction(ACTION.OPEN_ACTION);
    PendingIntent openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")
            .setContentTitle(bundle.getString("Title"))
            .setContentText(bundle.getString("Description"))
            .setContentIntent(openPendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION.PLAYER, notification);
```

Sample 1:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> (Notification click)`

i want this:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity Z`

OR

Sample 2:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> (Notification click)`

I want this:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity Z`

OR

Sample 3:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> (Home button) -> (Notification click)`

I want this:

`Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity Z`

but I have this at all samples:

`Activity Z ->(Back press)-> Home screen`

Comment: I didn't get your question

Comment: @Opriday Check my update

Comment: so you want ...when you back button is pressed... you want to go back as the same path you have come...is that right

Comment: @lllllllllllllll yes

Comment: possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614429/notification-opens-activity-back-button-pressed-main-activity-is-opened]

Comment: go to this link ...you will get the answer

Comment: @llllllllllllll Check my update (sample 3)

Comment: I want push new activity to current back stack of my app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176467/discussion-between-lllllllllllllll-and-h-danesh).

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

are you override onBackPress method in that activity?

for this you most define onBackPress method in that activity like below to go to MainActivity when user press back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    Intent intent=new Intent(thatActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Previous activity is not always MainActivity.

Comment: Sure. This was just an example @H.Danesh

Comment: This is not necessary or useful. Standard behaviour should take the user back to the previous `Activity` in his task. Your suggestion implies that the user knows what the previous `Activity` is. This is bad architecture and not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303663/android-resume-app-from-previous-position).

by adding this line:

```
openIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. The linked question shows how to bring an existing task to the foreground **without launching a new `Activity` into it**. You want to launch a new `Activity` into an existing task. Please post your manifest and maybe we can figure out your problem. Adding a CATEGORY to the `Intent` shouldn't make any difference at all.